# Помогите в поиске метода Laravel

Tags: laravel

Какой метод в Laravel сможет минуя код ниже обновить запись?

```
$statuses = Statuses::where('base_id', $request->id)->where('status_id', 1)->get();

if (!$statuses->isEmpty()) {

    $statuses = Statuses::where('base_id', $request->id)->update(['status_id' => 2]);

}
```

Comment: Миня код ниже, это какой код? Ниже как раз обновление записи)

Comment: И там в проверке status = 1, а в обновлении status = 2

Comment: Я имею ввиду есть ли встроенный метод чтоб сократить мой код

Comment: Так а это нормально что при выборке проверяется статус, а при обновлении нет, он обновить может все записи с base_id таким, если статус не играет роли, почему он в выборке в самом начале принимает условие?

Answer (score 0):

Можно записать так

```
    Statuses::where('base_id', $request->id)
            ->where('status_id', 1)
            ->update('[
                    'status_id' => 2
            ]');
```

Если соответствующий записей найдено не будет, следовательно и обновляться ничего не будет...